# What is the purpose or wrapping a protected function with a public one which does the same thing?

Tags: php, function, oop, inheritance

I have a some legacy code which I am currently looking to cut down and make usable in a new project. I've come across the following class with lots of protected methods which perform the intended functionality but they are accessed via a public method which just wraps them like so:

```
/**
 * method used to perform a fetch both using passed in SQL and optional params
 * @param string - SQL to be executed
 * @param array - optional - used if the query is to be prepared
 * @return mixed - false on failure or array on success
**/
protected function _fetcharray($sql, $params = [])
{
    //execute the query and return the results  
    return $this->execute($sql, $params)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
}

/**
 * Public implementeation of __fetcharray
 * @param string - SQL to be executed
 * @param array - optional - used if the query is to be prepared
 * @return mixed - false on failure or array on success
 **/
public function fetcharray($sql, $params = [])
{
    //execute the query and return the results
    return $this->_fetcharray($sql, $params);
}
```

I can understand that it might be necessary to do somethings  privately which you would not want to expose publicly but considering one function just calls the other what is the point of this. i.e what am I missing here?

Comment: This is done to keep things future proof. At the time of implementation there is nothing to be kept back, so the inner method could also be exposed public. However that might change in future, things might get more complicated and a separation might be required. With the approach you see the inner method can be modified later without changing the outer appearance.

Answer (score 2):

The "owner" of the protected function can change the implementation details - perhaps even adding new function parameters - safe in the knowledge that it will not break as much code as directly changing the public function would.

Technically, the `public` function can be referred to as a *stub*.

If the inner function were marked `private` then the degree of encapsulation would be greater still.

Answer (score 1):

As is, this seems pretty pointless. The author probably intended to keep some flexibility somewhere and be able to swap out the implementation details of the public method... but it looks to me like they didn't exactly think it all the way through.

The core issue is *API stability*. That means, once you expose a `public function fetcharray($sql, $params = [])`, there will be other code written which calls this function. If you want to change the *`public` interface* later, i.e. rename the function or change the number or meaning of its parameters, you're stuck because now there's a whole bunch of other code which depends on the name and parameters to be as they are.

However, you are still entirely free to change the innards of the function entirely. As long as the function name, the parameters and the return value(s) don't change, you can rewrite the function from scratch anytime you like.

So what's the advantage of having a "private" implementation and proxying the `public` function through to it? None. It still requires you to keep the `public` API stable and it doesn't offer anymore flexibility than you'd already have otherwise.

*Perhaps* the author intended for inheriting classes to call the `protected` function and for other external code to call the `public` function, which seems reasonable; but then they failed to provide any reasoning for this or any clear distinction between these two different functions. If the `protected` function behaved subtly different than the `public` one, this might make some sort of sense; but since they don't, this seems to be a simple brainfart. Now they've got *two* APIs to maintain instead of one, arguably decreasing maintainability rather than increasing it.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have pointed out, it makes sense (if we assume sense was in play here) if the author intended for the `public` function to be adjustable, while the `protected` function remained absolute. Therefore, the author could always rely on the `private` method behaving as expected, while leaving other developers to edit the public one in their implementation.

However, this doesn't quite make sense since the `protected` function is still adjustable itself. The author probably should have made the function `private` and `final` to prevent editing.

Intention aside, this is still a very poor implementation as `_fetcharray` just wraps `execute` which, assuming the underscore in `_fetcharray` was being used as a standard for "not public", is probably a `public` method. So what you have is a `public` method, wrapping a `private` method, wrapping a `public` method, which it would always make more sense to use in the first place.

I call pasta.